# Rollupjs emits '"this" has been rewritten to "undefined"'. How can I address this issue?

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, tslib

Running `pnpm install && pnpm build` on the simple project below is throwing warning

```
"this" has been rewritten to "undefined"
```

Investigating a bit it seems that the code trying to be compiled is coming from **tslib**. The compiler doesn't know what value `this` is, so it replaces it with `undefined`. I'm trying to create a library here that should be run in browser and nodejs. I don't know how to fix this.

---

I can reproduce it with these:

- **nodejs: v18.16.0**
- **pnpm: 8.5.1**
- **TypeScript: 5.0.4**
- **rollup: v3.22.0**

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "rollup-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fp-ts": "^2.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

*rollup.config.js*

```js
const typescript = require('@rollup/plugin-typescript');
const { nodeResolve } = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');

module.exports = [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/index.cjs.js',
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    plugins: [
      nodeResolve(), 
      typescript()
    ]
  }
];
```

*src/index.ts*

```
import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either'

function mylog(str: string) {
  const x = E.right(str)

  if (E.isLeft(x)) {
    console.log(x.left)
  } else {
    console.log(x.right)
  }
}

mylog('hi')
```

Running `pnpm build` outputs:

```
> rollup-test@1.0.0 build /Users/theuser/Desktop/rollup-test
> rollup -c rollup.config.js


src/index.ts → dist/index.cjs.js...
(!) "this" has been rewritten to "undefined"
https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules/.pnpm/fp-ts@2.15.0/node_modules/fp-ts/es6/function.js
1: var __spreadArray = (this && this.__spreadArray) || function (to, from, pack) {
                        ^
2:     if (pack || arguments.length === 2) for (var i = 0, l = from.length, ar; i < l; i++) {
3:         if (ar || !(i in from)) {
...and 1 other occurrence
node_modules/.pnpm/fp-ts@2.15.0/node_modules/fp-ts/es6/internal.js
1: var __spreadArray = (this && this.__spreadArray) || function (to, from, pack) {
                        ^
2:     if (pack || arguments.length === 2) for (var i = 0, l = from.length, ar; i < l; i++) {
3:         if (ar || !(i in from)) {
...and 1 other occurrence
created dist/index.cjs.js in 369ms
```

Comment: Just learned that I can use `context` property in `rollup.config.js`. Not sure if I set it to `globalThis` covers most of the use cases